# How to upgrade debian VM with more CPUs

Tags: debian, virtualization

For some reason whoever built the server I'm working on only gave it 2 CPUs in the hyper-visor, I can easily give it 4, but I'm positive that will break it,  the kernel will not recognize the others.. I vaguely remember trying this exactly a while back and gave up.. "if it ain't broke" etc..

However, the load on the server is increasing, I will be increasing the size of the hard-drives and need to increase the amount of CPU/RAM etc too.. (Physical RAM is on order for the box, but I have a few Gb free I can allocate)

What do I do?

I'm hoping its a simple matter of "installing the kernel" then rebooting with new CPU's allocated, but I want some advice/tips/help first.

Also, Any idea what kernel I need?

ESX Seems to be configured for Linux 32 bit, can I just change this to 64?
https://wiki.debian.org/Migrate32To64Bit suggests I have to do a lot of fluffing about..

https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel wasn't very helpful.

Possibly helpful info:

```
apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://archive.debian.org lenny/non-free Packages
     release v=5.0.10,o=Debian,a=oldstable,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin archive.debian.org
 500 http://archive.debian.org lenny/main Packages
     release v=5.0.10,o=Debian,a=oldstable,l=Debian,c=main
     origin archive.debian.org
 500 http://archive.debian.org lenny/contrib Packages
     release v=5.0.10,o=Debian,a=oldstable,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin archive.debian.org
Pinned packages:


uname -a
Linux webserv 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Sun Mar 4 22:19:19 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux

/boot$ ls
config-2.6.26-2-686  grub  initrd.img-2.6.26-2-686  initrd.img-2.6.26-2-686.bak  System.map-2.6.26-2-686  vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-686
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz
stepping    : 8
cpu MHz     : 2261.000
cache size  : 8192 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida
bogomips    : 4527.01
clflush size    : 64
power management:
```

Not that I'm incredibly lazy or anything.. but I'm thinking it might be easier to simply start from scratch with a new VM and migrate the data/services..

Comment: Lenny has been EOL for a couple years now.

Comment: *scrambles to google* So it is!. I try not to touch this server too much (production database).. but now I'm thinking the nuke & pave option might be the best for everyone.

Comment: Get at *least* Squeeze and see about upgrading to Wheezy.

Comment: Eh, you've got it virtual? Launch a second image of the thing on a separate IP address, `apt-get dist-upgrade` to Squeeze, check if everything works, upgrade to Wheezy, check again, mirror the databases one last time, swap the IP addresses, done.

Comment: You do not need to do anything special with the kernel. Shut down, increase the number of CPUs in the hypervisor, boot the VM, that's it. Which isn't to say that reinstalling wouldn't be a good idea, as you're two Debian releases behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from 32-bit to 64-bit isn't necessarily complicated, but given that you're two full release cycles behind it's *probably* best if you create a fresh VM, install Wheezy, and then see about copying over the data.

How viable this is will depend largely on what kinds of services you're running and how much custom configuration work you've done to them -- I recently ran into some trouble with a truly ancient legacy MySQL server setup (originally predating Lenny) and a bunch of config options that were suboptimal at best and outright incompatible with more modern versions of MySQL at worst. Not one of my smoother upgrades, all told...

Barring more specific information, I can only give some general advice: Install each service on the new setup, then look through modern documentation to see what config options exist and what they all do, then manually compare them to the config you've originally set up on the current server, and decide what needs to be retained and what's best left in the past.

Comment: Yup, I'm making a new vm just for the database. It's currently lamp so apache should be fine with that. Will migrate that too when decoupled. Mysql is by far the resource hog.